# Linq to SQL - order by two columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have two columns, "date added" and "date modified".

I want to order all products by date modified, but since it can be null i want to get date added in that case.

```
 var q = from c in db.Products
                where c.UserID == UserID
                orderby c.DateModified ?? c.DateAdded descending
                select
                    new ManageProducts
                        {
                            ID = c.ID,
                            Image = c.Photo.PhotoFile,
                            Name = c.Name,
                            DateAdded = (DateTime) c.DateModified ?? c.DateAdded 
};
```

This show me an error on

```
DateAdded = (DateTime) c.DateModified ?? c.DateAdded
```

[image: Error]

Comment: `c.DateModified.Value` try this.

Comment: try with `DateAdded = c.DateModified.HasValue ? c.DateModified.Value : c.DateAdded`

Answer (score 1):

try remove the cast (DateTime) in

```
DateAdded = (DateTime) c.DateModified ?? c.DateAdded
```

I've wrote snippet and in works fine

```
var sample = new [] {new {Nul = (int?) 5,    Val = 6}, 
                     new {Nul = (int?) null, Val = 6}};

var res = from value in sample 
          orderby value.Nul ?? value.Val
          select new {Val = value.Nul ?? value.Val};
```

Just to make sure:

```
Console.WriteLine (typeof(int) == res.ElementAt(0).Val.GetType()); //True
Console.WriteLine (typeof(int?) == res.ElementAt(0).Val.GetType()); //False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
DateAdded = c.DateModified.HasValue ? c.DateModified.Value : c.DateAdded
```

You're trying to assign nullable DateTime (c.DateModified) to a non-nullable DateTime field (DateAdded). You must take the value from nullable property if it exists or use another value (in your case c.DateAdded)

Comment: DateAdded = c.DateModified != null ? c.DateModified.Value : c.DateAdded.Value - this works fine